# How to convert "../../lib/libopencv_videoio.so" to "libopencv_videoio.so" when building opencv library?

Tags: c++, linux, opencv, ubuntu-18.04

I am using cmake to build opencv3.4.0 in ubuntu18.04.The compilers are arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc and arm-linux-gnueabihf-g++.

But when I finish the building work, I check the dependency of lib libopencv_highgui.so by "readelf -d libopencv_highgui.so",I get following message:

0x00000001 (NEEDED)                     Shared library: [libpthread.so.0]

0x00000001 (NEEDED)                     Shared library: [librt.so.1]

0x00000001 (NEEDED)                     Shared library: [libdl.so.2]

0x00000001 (NEEDED)                     Shared library: [../../lib/libopencv_videoio.so]

0x00000001 (NEEDED)                     Shared library: [../../lib/libopencv_imgcodecs.so]

0x00000001 (NEEDED)                     Shared library: [../../lib/libopencv_imgproc.so]

0x00000001 (NEEDED)                     Shared library: [../../lib/libopencv_core.so]

0x00000001 (NEEDED)                     Shared library: [libstdc++.so.6]

0x00000001 (NEEDED)                     Shared library: [libm.so.6]

0x00000001 (NEEDED)                     Shared library: [libgcc_s.so.1]

0x00000001 (NEEDED)                     Shared library: [libc.so.6]

...

So my question is:

How to convert "../../lib/libopencv_videoio.so" to "libopencv_videoio.so" just like [libpthread.so.0].

Comment: I'm not sure but I think the problem is something else. Are you building some other library along with opencv too?

Comment: @Meisam， I cross compile opencv3.4.0 for Raspberry Pi 3B+ in Ubuntu18.04.